# Would a log transformation on my features change the elastic net result

Tags: feature-selection, data-transformation, elastic-net

We built the elastic net model on a set of my features and control features.
With that, we did various experiments to discuss the importance of the selected features.
For example, we showed more of my features are selected than control features across different lambda values.
Then, I realized that I did log-transformation twice on my features whereas the control features were log-transformed once.
Do I need to rerun all the experiments conducted with those values?

I mean, I believe we didn't need to normalize the feature values because the elastic net will do that automatically.
I am asking if the elastic net would do a similar thing so double log-transform wouldn't be a problem.

Thanks,